Old master branch out of sync
I have a master branch for a repo in Bitbucket, which was last updated back in 2017. Now I have a task to sync the latest release branch with master and need to bring all code from release into master.
I tried to create a pull request, but there were more than 1000+ files added/changed.
What would be the best way here to bring the code of release branch into master here and files are missed while merging
Please note, I need to keep master branch history.

@dani-vta I need to keep masters history. I have added that now in question.

Since you said that the master branch hasn't been worked on since 2017. I'm assuming that release was used as a main branch this whole time. So, I imagine that release branched off from master at some point, and that the main development continued on release. Therefore, even if the PR shows thousands of files added/updated, there shouldn't be anything to resolve. The PR will be solved as a fast-forward merge. This is true unless, someone kept working on master after release branched off from master. I think we need more info here.

@ dani-vta I am not very sure if someone kept working on master. If it merges with fast forward merge is it ok to go with it in this case ? If yes then after merge how can i ensure that all changes were added and nothing is missed.

A fast-forward would be the best scenario in your case, because it means that changes have only been added on top of master. You can check that by attempting a git merge --ff-only release in your local repository while master is checked out. Instead, if that is not the case, you need to understand whether the changes on master that are not present in release are useful for release's history (I doubt it since they would be 7 years old, but your company will the better judge).

@dani-vta I tried with git merge --ff-only release but it did not worked.I can ignore the changes from master, what i need is all code from release to but put in master in cleanest possible way.


I can ignore the changes from master, what i need is all code from release to but put in master in cleanest possible way.

The simplest and cleanest way to align the master branch to release is with a git reset --hard <commit>. The command basically resets the index and the working tree to the given commit, in your case release's HEAD commit, making the master branch point to the same commit referred by release.

Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since <commit> are discarded. Any untracked files or directories in the way of writing any tracked files are simply deleted.

# checking out the master branch
git checkout master

# Resetting the master branch to the HEAD commit of the release branch
git reset --hard release

# forcing the overriding of the master branch on the remote with your local version
git push --force origin master

If you cannot push directly to the master branch due to some branch protection rules on your remote, you can follow this answer.

Third approach from the comments
A third approach, where you need to keep master's history and the commits made on it after release branched off, could be via a simple merge.
In this scenario, since you would have commits over 7 years old, you might first want to check what changes have been introduced by the commits on master that are not present on release. To do that, just log every commit on master minus the ones on release.
git log --no-merges master ^release

Once you have a clearer picture of your current situation, you might want to rebase the master branch to get rid of some of the commits made after release's divergence. In that case, just supply the merge-base between master and release to the git rebase -i command. At this point, you can finally merge release into master.
# selecting the master branch
git checkout master

# rebasing the commits made after release diverged.
# this step can be skipped if no commits need to be droped.
git rebase -i $(git merge-base master release)

# merging release into master
git merge release


Thanks! But this will not rewrite the history of master? Also when i am doing git merge release its not showing any conflicts and merging by recursive strategy, so what if i do by this way, anything i will be missing ?

Yes, it will.  With git reset --hard, master's history will become release's. About the merge approach, if we consider that you couldn't perform a fast-forward merge, it means that master introduced some work after release branched off, more than 7 years ago. Just because the merge is not showing any conflicts, it doesn't mean that your code will keep working just fine after the merge. Be careful of what you're maintaining in your master branch. (1/2)

However, if you think that the merge is a viable solution, and you want to: 1. maintain master's history, 2. align its current content to release, 3. and discard any further commits on master made after release's branching, then the answer I've linked in my post is probably your best solution. In your case, the migration branch of the other answer corresponds to your release branch. (2/2)

I want to understand if I do merge here which is recursive(in this case)in what cases my master will be out of sync with release

If you merge release into master, the two will be aligned again. Keep in mind that the master branch needs to be re-merged with the current release branch after every release to keep them in sync. You should also have a develop branch, which is the one that collects the current set of changes for the next release. Once a release is approaching, a new release branch is created from develop, the new version deployed, the release branch merged into master, and then develop aligned to master. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

I understand that going forward release should be merged in master after deployment.But my question was what could I be missing if I do '''git merge release ''' recursive here vs if I do '''git rest --hard release'''.In which case even after the recursive merge there cloud be differences in these two branches.

If you perform git merge release, your master branch will have all the changes from the release branch, plus the commits belonging only to master that have been made after release branched from master. You could perform a git log --no-merges master ^release to see all the commits on master that are not present in release and choose whether you want to maintain those changes or not.

On last question if i do git reset --hard release like you suggested then going forward there will be no issues in merging next release branch into master right?

@AWS_Beginner Since release's history will also become master's history, there will be no problems. It's also very important to adhere to the actual workflow of Gitflow. Keeping your master branch behind for 7 years is definitely a serious flaw in your development style.

@Thanks!! This is we something we want to correct and hence we need a one time sync of master with release.
